# Site with a 'hidden' submit button for Search not working on local server

Tags: php, search, localhost

I'm making a site that will be stored locally via an XAMPP local server in a museum. On one of the pages I have a search box. The idea is that you type into this search box to perform a PHP search, with no need for a 'search' button.. it's dynamic.

All has worked beautifully until moving it from an online server (for testing) to a local host (for proper use). All I get now is the word 'Submit' but  no functionality

Here is my javascript for turning the keystrokes into a search, and below that is my form.

I'm using Windows 7 and have tried on all browsers. Any ideas lovely people of Stackoverflow

Javascript:

```
<!--Javascript to turn keystrokes into search value-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

      // Hide the submit button
      $(":submit").hide();

      // Bind an event to the keypress in order to override the form submission when pressing the enter key
      $("input[name='search_term']").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
          // prevent the form from submitting in the normal manner (return key)
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      });

      // Bind an event to the keypress event of the text box
      $("input[name='search_term']").keyup(function () {
        // Get the search value
        var search_value = $(this).val();

        // This time we're going to grab data from a file to display
        var filename = "functions/function-search.php";

        // Send these values
        var posting = $.post(filename, { search_term: search_value });

        // Display this value in our results container
        posting.done(function (data) {
          $("#search_results").empty().append(data);
        });
      });

    });
  </script>
```

HTML Form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="search_term" class="file_lable_search_box" id="search"  size="10" maxlength="20" border="none" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You have to submit your form. But you can use e.preventDefault to stop it from actually performing the action.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I'm confused as it's worked beautifully before. In practice using your suggestion what do I need to do?

Comment: actually I think I mis-stated. I will put some code up for you to test..

Comment: jmadden is meaning when you link to your jquery. Is it a local file or are you using a hotlink. Link <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' /></script> Are you sure that it is truely loading java.

Comment: I think you have hit the nail on the head... my link to jquerry is <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"> which of course is NEVER going to work when the machine is offline Thanks guys, I'll download a copy and keep trying. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the head of your site and the way you are referencing Javascript files/libraries, I'd guess that it could be a referencing problem. Moving from online to a local instance you may need to adjust the way you are referencing Javascript files. I'd also suggest not using XAMPP for a production server, locally or otherwise, as it's main purpose is for development environments.

Comment: thanks jmadden, that's really helpful of you - Funny as it works OK on a testing machine locally, but now I'm rolling out problems. Would you mind elaborating on what you mean by referenceing the Javascript files. I can send bits of my code